# VideoCapture Camera index out of range

Tags: python, opencv, orbbec

When I run this below script

```
   import os

import cv2


DATA_DIR = './data'
if not os.path.exists(DATA_DIR):
    os.makedirs(DATA_DIR)

number_of_classes = 3
dataset_size = 100

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
for j in range(number_of_classes):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, str(j))):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, str(j)))

    print('Collecting data for class {}'.format(j))

    done = False
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Ready? Press "Q" ! :)', (100, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.3, (0, 255, 0), 3,
                    cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) == ord('q'):
            break
        else:
            break
        

    counter = 0
    while counter < dataset_size:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(25)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, str(j), '{}.jpg'.format(counter)), frame)

        counter += 1
   
           

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Getting this error, **Please Help!**

> [ERROR:0@0.156] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
> out of range
> Collecting data for class 0
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\Final Year Project\Proj_By_Me\collect_imgs.py", line 26, in 
> cv2.imshow('frame', frame)                                                                              (-215:Assertion f
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error:
> (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: `Camera index out of range`. what do you think it means?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Got the solution, cv2.videocapture(2) is for external camera which is connected to the system and cv2.videocapture(0) is for the internal camera. I used '0' and it worked sorry wasn't able to figure out as i am a beginner. Thank You!

Comment: You should check `while cap.isOpened():` instead of `while True:`

Comment: isOpened() should be checked once at least, right after instance creation. in the loop, more vitally: `if not ret: break` (if a read fails, it will probably keep failing)

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding this import ->  `from pathlib import Path`.
2. cv2.videocapture(2) is for external camera which is connected to the system and cv2.videocapture(0) is for the internal camera. I used '0' and it worked.

From these I was able to fix it.